# Sitecore 6 Is it possible to change roles for virtual user when already logged in?

Tags: security, sitecore, sitecore6

In **Sitecore 6** is it possible to change roles for virtual user when already logged in?

I would like to change roles for virtual users that are already logged in to system, but it looks like Sitecore ignores it. I can clear roles and add a new one but all the old roles are still attached to the user.
I think I should to re-login the user but it is not the case for me.

```cs
virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Clear();
virtualUser.Roles.RemoveAll();
if (permissions != null && permissions.Any())
{
    foreach (var role in permissions.Where(d=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Type)))
    {
        string domainRole = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", "extranet", role.Type);
        if (SC.Security.Accounts.Role.Exists(domainRole))
        {
            virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Add(domainRole);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use

```
Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.ClearSecurityCache(userName);
```

This method calls another methods:

```
CacheManager.ClearUserProfileCache(userName);
CacheManager.ClearIsInRoleCache(userName);
CacheManager.ClearAccessResultCache(userName);
```

So in theory it should do what you need but I haven't confirmed it in practice.

Comment: This clears the cache, but I'm not sure if the new Roles/Profile are added again and available in the context. A trial-and-error should come to a conclusion ;)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be that login-out and re-login will set the correct roles because during login the `AuthenticationManager` will clear the SecurityCache which holds the `UserProfile` and the `Roles`.
I don't see a method to add new Roles to the current authenticated user.